# Creating a function to restart while loop

Tags: python

I'm creating a text based adventure game and when the user's health gets to 0, I ask them if they want to restart the game. This works fine - however, I am duplicating my code a lot inside this while loop and want to know how to create a function which I can call to restart the game.

This is the code I use to restart:

```
if health <= 0:
    print('You died. Do you want to restart? (y/n)')
    ans = input().lower()
    if ans == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You can't use a function to execute `break` or `continue` "on behalf" of the loop that the function is called from. The best you could do by introducing a function is to have the function return some data (like a standardized version of what the user entered), and running the appropriate statement using that data. You could also represent the game logic in an object, alter a object attribute within the function (`state.should_continue`?), then have the while loop check that (`while state.should_continue:`). It's hard to say with so little context though.

Comment: U dont seem to have a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, but this is one.

The following function will return `True` if the user enters `'yes'`, and `False` otherwise:

```py
def continue_prompt():
    typewriter('You now have 0 health and lose the game.')
    print('\nDo you want to restart? (yes/no)')
    return input().lower() == 'yes':
```

The below code will [short circuit](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/short-circuiting-techniques-python/) if `health` isn't `0`, so the function will only be called in the event that the character has died. Then it will `continue` or `break` depending on the return value of `continue_prompt`.

```py
if health <= 0 and continue_prompt():
    continue
else:
    break
```

You could also customize the prompt by having `continue_prompt` accept one or more arguments, if you wanted it to say different things for different causes of death, for instance.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a custom exception and raise it when healths is 0. Then it's possible to move all the health affecting to a reusable function that handles death. Just call the function to change health instead of adding or subtracting

Define the exception:

```
class DeceaseException(Exception):
    pass
```

And a function for handling health

```
def affect_health(gain):
    global health
    health += gain
    if health <= 0:
        raise DeceaseException
```

Wherever the health is affected you put for example:

```
# health decreases
affect_health(-10)
```

And in main function:

```
while True:
    try:
        # main game code
    except DeceaseException:
        print('You died. Do you want to restart? (y/n)')
        ans = input().lower()
        if ans == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about raising an exception for control flow, even when nothing went "wrong", but this is honestly pretty clever. You could even do something like `raise RestartException('You died because...')` and then pass the error to `print` or `typewriter`, to get custom death/restart prompts.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I believe death is as "went wrong" it could get :)

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming this is just sitting inside of a `while` loop?

If so, one option could be

```
if not health:
   typewriter('You now have 0 health and lose the game.')
   restart = input('\nDo you want to restart? (yes/no)')
   if restart.lower() == 'yes':
      continue
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because `continue` doesn't restart

Comment: @SrishruthikAlle  If this code block is inside of a while loop as mentioned then yes it does.

Comment: This would still have to be cut and pasted everywhere you want it to happen, though. `continue` wouldn't work inside a function call. (Also you have a syntax error.)